# Disable class inhernces on particular page ID

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery Mobile for web App. On this project developers override some of the main jQuery Mobile classes like:

```
 .ui-btn-text
 .ui-icon
 .ui-btn-corner-all
```

for example:

```
.ui-btn-text {
    color:#fff;
    padding:6px 10px;
    line-height:10px;
    font-size:12px;
    /* 

    some settings....

    */
}
```

I'm adding some new `input` and automatically it inherits from the overridden class. How can I disable this inherited on particular page, so it will work with the jQuery Mobile classes, for example disable it for **#pageTest**.

Comment: instead of overriding jqm classes globally. Make classes and add them to items. This is easier for maintenance/manipulating classes and elements.

Comment: like this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/kGrQp/

Comment: @Omar, The situation now is that I can't change it because lot of things related to those classes on this project. I prefer to disable this for particular page.

Comment: can you show how do you override the styles?

Comment: I added to my question the class style overridden...I just set some style settings to existing JQM class.

Comment: ok, I will tell you what to do in this case, i'll prepare a fiddle to explain more

Comment: I dont think there is any better way than this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/ygBZY/. create custom styles and add/remove them wherever/whenever you want.

Comment: @Zeaklous, I didn't get answered...all the answers are saying : do custom classes for the specific places, but I cant change the code of all project. I just want to reset it in some places. The problem is from where to take the original settings, if I open the style file, so for example `ui-btn-inner` exist there more than 20 times in different places. Do I have to copy it to 1 new class?

Comment: @Dima look at my answer below: it takes a button of class `.ui-btn-text` and ID `#pageTest` and changes only that specific combination of id and class properties.

Comment: Yes, But that's not what I asked! my question is, after it's already overridden in the project without specific ID, it overridden like `.ui-btn-text { position: relative; z-index: 1; }`  (Cant touch it) how can I use it with the original **JQM** setting and not the overridden ones.

Comment: @Dima That's exactly what I'm saying too, haha. The only way to do it is to apply a new class to each element or to use javascript and change the CSS of each with the class `.ui-btn-text` manually by iterating through them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just reset it back to the original values according to [jQuery mobile's stylesheet](http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.css). If it's the un-minified version of the jQuery, it can be found [here](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css).

[Here is an example of that in practice](http://jsfiddle.net/qDxnK/1/). For your example that look like

```
#pageTest.ui-btn-text { position: relative; z-index: 1; }
```

The only other option is to use javascript and iterate through each instance of the class. Using jQuery would be easiest:

```
$('.ui-btn-text').each(function() {
    $(this).css({
        'position' : 'relative',
        'z-index':'1',
        //etc...
    });
});
```